# SQL Loader - no terminator found after TERMINATED and ENCLOSED field - dirty data

Tags: oracle, sql-loader, ctl

I am getting a "no terminator found after TERMINATED and ENCLOSED field" error in the Oracle SQL Loader utility

in this case there are quotes also into a field
here my CTL

```
  OPTIONS (SKIP=1)
LOAD DATA
TRUNCATE
INTO TABLE TABLE_NAME
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
TRAILING NULLCOLS 
(
FIELD_1                  "TRIM(:FIELD_1)",
FIELD_2                  "TRIM(:FIELD_2)"
)
```

Example file with discards

"AAAA00000";"FIELD OK";

"BBBB11111";"FIELD CAUSES "DISCARD"";

there is a option i can use into clt to load also the second record?

thks

Comment: Are you able to change how the data file is generated? If not, [can you preprocess it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41442670/266304)?

Comment: you can use the STR clause to allow for the quotes in the strings to be escaped, examples here https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/asktom.search?tag=how-to-preserver-double-quotes-in-the-data-using-sqlloader-data-load#9533956100346976174