# sqlldr is failing due to more than 2 double quotes in a column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, sql-loader

The problem is when I put more than two double quote in the NAME column (check below code) then sqlldr fails.
In **data.txt** file, first 3 records are failing because the NAME column (2nd position in the record) has more than 2 double quotes.
Please assist. I think some function I need to put in control file against NAME column.

**You can run the below code and check, first 3 records will fail and the last record will get inserted, I want to insert all records with or without double quote:**

```
--table creation
    create table employee
    (      
      name varchar2(4000)      
    );


--control file
load data
 infile '/tmp/swetabh/data.txt' 
 into table employee
 truncate
 fields terminated by "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED by '"'  TRAILING NULLCOLS 
 (
 name      
 )


--data.txt (SEE ALL RECORDS ARE HAVING MORE THAN 2 DOUBLE QUOTE AND WANT TO INSERT DATA TO THE TABLE WITH OR WITHOUT DOUBLE QUOTE)
""start with double quote       "
"end with double quote          ""
"double quote " in the middle   "
```

-bash-4.1$ sqlldr userid=xxx/xxx@xxxx control=/tmp/swetabh/control.txt log=/tmp/swetabh/control.log bad=/tmp/swetabh/bad.txt readsize=2000000000 bindsize=2000000000

Comment: There's some extended discussion about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41431545/oracle-sql-loader-handling-efficiently-internal-double-quotes-in-values

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any control over the extract portion of the process?  If so can you specify that double-quotes in the data get doubled-up 
(quoted)? Or even better, specify the use of pipes as delimiters and no surrounding double-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

How about applying `REPLACE` function which will *replace* double quote (`CHR(34)`) with *nothing* (`NULL`)? Also, remove `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED` clause.

Control file:

```
load data 
infile *
replace
into table employee
fields terminated by "," TRAILING NULLCOLS 
(
name "replace(:name, chr(34), null)"    
)

begindata
""start with double quote       "
"end with double quote          ""
"double quote " in the middle   "
```

Testing:

```
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger control=test04.ctl log=test04.log

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Uto O×u 19 19:14:49 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 2
Commit point reached - logical record count 3

SQL> select * From employee;

NAME
--------------------------------------------------
start with double quote
end with double quote
double quote  in the middle

SQL>
```

Comment: We have terminator as comma and String may contain comma so it is surrounded by Double Quote. I have multiple columns in the file. I cannot change the terminator. 
The problem arise when there are more than two double quote after comma. PleasE copy below data to your text editor 
"1","2col",""3col   "    "
"2","2col"," "3c,ol   "    "
"3","2col"," 3co,l"    "
"4","2col","3co,l"
"5","2col",""3co,l    ""    "
"6","2col",""3c,ol ""3c,ol"""
Create table employee ( id number, comments varchar2(4000) , name varchar2(4000) );